# Huge bias in IV during Monte Carlo Simulations

Tags: monte-carlo, bias, instrumental-variables

I am trying to see how IV performs with Monte Carlo Simulations. My model is:
$y = X \beta + p \alpha + \xi + \epsilon $. In this model $ \xi $ is not observed and $p$ is correlated with $\xi$. So I use an instrumental variable $z$ which is correlated with $p$ but is not correlated with $\xi + \epsilon$. However, for $\alpha$, I get erratic results. For example, I set $\alpha = -5$, however, I get values as high as $\pm 400$ for $\alpha$ in some of the simulations. This occurs when I use around 100 observations which to me is surprising. I couldn't figure out what I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.

If you also have a reach a well-performing IV Monte Carlo Simulation, it will help me to spot my problem. My Code is:

```
#Cleaning
rm(list = ls())

library(MASS)
library(AER)

#Number of observations
obs <- 100
#Number of characteristics
k <- 4

#Assign the mean values of X
mu.x <- rep(0, k)

#Assign the variance covariance matrix of X
sigma.x <- matrix(diag(rep(2, k)), ncol = k)

#Sigma for correlated price and instrumental variable
sigma.ins <- matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), ncol = 2)


nsim = 500

#slope values for x characteristics
coeff.x <- as.vector(c(4, 4, 2, 2, rep(0, k-4)))
beta.p <- -5

#Assign names for the columns
xnam <- paste("X", 1:k, sep = "")

#OLS regression formula
fm.olsreg = paste0("y ~ ", 
                   paste(xnam, collapse = " + "), " + ", 
                   paste("p", collapse = " + "))

#IV regression formula
fm.ivreg = paste0("y ~ ", 
                  paste(xnam, collapse = " + "), " + ", 
                  paste("p", collapse = " + "),  " | ",
                  paste(xnam, collapse = " + "), " + ",
                  paste("z", collapse = " + "))


#Storing p coefficient for IV and OLS
p.values <- matrix(NaN, nrow = nsim, ncol = 2)

for (sim in 1:nsim) {
  #Creating x characteristics for each of j products in t markets
  X.jt <- mvrnorm(obs, mu = mu.x, Sigma = sigma.x)
  
  #The base values for price and instrumental variable
  p.raw.z <- mvrnorm(obs, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = sigma.ins)
  
  #Creating the endogenous part
  xi.jt <- as.matrix(rnorm(obs, 0, 3/2))
  
  #real p data corrlated with xi
  p.jt <- p.raw.z[,1] + xi.jt
  
  #instrumental variable correlated with p
  z.jt <- p.raw.z[,2] + rnorm(obs, 0, 0.3)
  
  #creating errors
  e.jt <- rnorm(obs, 0, 0.8)
  
  #Producing y variables
  y <- X.jt %*% coeff.x + p.jt*beta.p + xi.jt +  e.jt
  
  #putting everything together
  data <- as.matrix(cbind(X.jt, p.jt, xi.jt, z.jt, y))
 
  #Assigning names to related columns
  colnames(data)[1:as.integer(k+4)] <- c(xnam, 'p', 'xi', 'z', 'y')
  
  #OLS regression
  ols = lm(data = as.data.frame(data),
           formula = fm.olsreg)
  
  #IV regression
  mo.ivreg <- ivreg(data = as.data.frame(data),
                    formula = fm.ivreg)
  
  #Store p values for both method
  p.values[sim,1] <- mo.ivreg$coefficients['p']
  p.values[sim, 2] <- ols$coefficients['p']
  
}

plot(density(p.values[,1]))
plot(density(p.values[,2]))

summary(p.values)
```

You may get for $\alpha$ something like

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{IV} & \text{OLS} \\ \hline
\text{Min} & -15.843 & -4.530 \\ \hline
\text{Mean} & -4.575 & -4.309 \\ \hline
\text{Max} & 285.922 & -4.083 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I vote to leave open, a statistical issue is, IMO, at the heart of this question: IV has a moment issue for low degrees of overidentification, see e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/1912027. So outliers are to be expected.

Comment: @ChristophHanck thanks for the answer, you are probably right, in overidentified case I've experienced more acceptable biases. So, it seems like solving this issue is possible by using more observations and using more instruments. since I've got the chance, thanks for the book "Introduction to Metrics with R" as well. I've used it to self-learn R and it was really helpful.

Comment: thanks for your kind words on our book, always great to hear when it is useful!